# 'Add Service Reference' not working with Azure AppFabric ServiceBus June 2011 CTP

Tags: azure, appfabric, servicebus

I have a computer with no AppFabric sdks installed (neither V1 or V2 CTP). I added a reference to the Microsoft.ServiceBus dll (June 2011 CTP version). When I try to add a Service Reference to Azure Service running locally, I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceBus,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies

I'm not sure why is it trying to get version 1. I even got service model extensions on the web.config and machine.config pointing to version 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I had some machine.config entries still pointing to version 1. Specifically on the policyImporters node. I just changed them to version 2 and it worked!